# START_STICKY for Foreground Services

Tags: android, service

A `Foreground Service` has a very high priority and is very unlikely to be killed by the system, so is there any point in returning `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand`?

Edit: This question is not about the difference between `START_STICKY` and `START_NON_STICKY`, it's about the usability of `START_STICKY` in relation to Foreground Services.

Answer (score 5):

"is very unlikely to be killed" != "will never be killed". For example, the user can terminate your process through a variety of means.

If you care about those scenarios and want to have your service be restarted (when eligible), use `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`. If you are happy to let the service stay dead, use `START_NOT_STICKY`.

For example, if you are writing a music player, return `START_NOT_STICKY`, as it may not be appropriate for your app to start playing music at some arbitrary time later when the system elects to restart your service.

Comment: Oddly though the START_STICKY docs state: "This mode makes sense for things that will be explicitly started and stopped to run for arbitrary periods of time, such as a service performing background music playback."

Comment: @Elletlar: I have never agreed with that recommendation from Google. I think I even filed an issue on it, but documentation issues tend to get routed to `/dev/null` in the Googleplex.

Comment: I guess the recommendation would make sense if the service is restarted very soon after it stops, but there is no guarantee of that.

Comment: Can you give an example for when the system will kill a foreground service that is playing music?

Comment: @FlorianWalther: If the user presses Force Stop in Settings, Android will terminate the process. Apparently, in some situations, removing the task from the overview screen will terminate a process despite a foreground service. Users might have a third-party "task manager" that terminates the process. And, due to old age, Android might terminate the process as part of the ordinary out-of-memory-killer logic. A foreground service does not live forever.

Comment: Ok thank you, but is my conclusion correct that the START_STICKY plays a less important role for foreground services than for background services (pre Oreo)

Comment: @FlorianWalther: I would not phrase it that way. It is less likely that your choice of `START_STICKY` vs. `START_NOT_STICKY` will play a role.

Comment: I have a little question that is too basic to open a new question here, but I can't really find a solution online. Maybe you can answer it: Should I build the foreground notification and call `startForeground` in the `onCreate` method of the `Service`, or in `onStartCommand`?

Comment: @FlorianWalther: I can't answer that. It would depend on the nature of the service.

Comment: Ok, so both are reasonable under different circumstances? That's all I need to know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170634/discussion-between-florian-walther-and-commonsware).